# How do I execute an external command without jumping out of vim?

Tags: external-command

I want to execute some external program to format my code.

```
:silent execute "!eslint --fix -o /dev/null %" | redraw!
```

But the screen will jump to the shell output screen and shortly back to vim again. How I can avoid this short flash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the external command is executed via the shell, you need to append an ampersand (`&`) to launch the process in the background:

```
:silent execute '!eslint --fix -o /dev/null % &' | execute ':redraw!'
```

You could also try the plugin [vim-fixmyjs](https://github.com/ruanyl/vim-fixmyjs).

Then, to format on save, just add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
au BufWritePre *.js :Fixmyjs
au BufWritePre *.jsx :Fixmyjs
```